# Setting up home VLAN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vlan

I'm having problems with setting up VLANs in my home network, or coming up with a good concept in the first place. I have to say that I'm not new to networking and even subnetting, but I'm a newby on VLANs.

I have 3 main groups of devices as follows:

**Group 1** *(PCs and Notebooks via LAN)*

Devices in group 1 should be able to communicate with each other and have connection to the internet. My own devices as well as guests who connect their PC/Notebook via LAN should be handled in the same way.

**Group 2** *(Servers and other network devices)*

The purpose of group 2 is to exclude it's devices from broadcasts from group 1 and create a logical segment to which the access can be restricted/allowed for some users.

**Group 3** *(WLAN / Guest)*

Devices in group 3 should have access to the internet but not to any other group's members. Maybe even no communication between each other...

**Addition**

- My PC from group 1 should have access to all members of group 2, but no one else from group 1.
- I am currently using an Odroid mini pc as OpenVPN Server. My friends connect to it via Internet (Ports are forwarded) and I am connecting to it as well. But I don't know where to place it in the new setup. Maybe there is a better solution so that only 'external' friends have to connect?
- The cameras are PoE powered and have thus to be connected to the switch directly

---

Group 3 could be realized by the 'guest' functions provided by my router (FRITZ!Box 7362SL). But as far as I know the 'only internet' option stands for a restriction to port 80 and that is not what I want.

Here is a graphic showing the groups and my idea of the setup:
[image: structure]

**My Questions**

- Is such a setup possible?
- Is it possible with the existing components?
- How would the VLAN configuration look
- Would it make more sense to move the printer to group 1 / VLAN1?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Although your switch is compatible with VLANs, your router is not, and your switch is not capable of doing inter-VLAN routing, so this will not work with your hardware setup. You need a much higher end router, like a mid to high end DD-WRT capable router or an enterprise grade router to handle the 3 unique networks your discussing. The best you can do is have your servers and regular network devices together with the normal wifi network, and use the guest WiFi just for guests (it has no access to any internal devices). Unfortunately, VLANing is not a simple thing to be done with home devices

Comment: @acejavelin that should be an answer, not a comment, shouldn't it? Thanks for havin a look on my plans. Could you give some tips for hardware and realization? I think especially the restriction parts should be done via ACL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your switch is compatible with VLANs, your router is not, and your switch is not capable of doing inter-VLAN routing, so this will not work with your hardware setup. You need a much higher end router, like a mid to high end DD-WRT capable router or an enterprise grade router to handle the 3 unique networks your discussing. The best you can do is have your servers and regular network devices together with the normal wifi network, and use the guest WiFi just for guests (it has no access to any internal devices). Unfortunately, VLANing is not a simple thing to be done with home devices.

Answer (score 1):

Comment about inter vlan routing was a very valid one.
Have a look at mikrotik products 
http://www.emsperformance.net/2012/11/24/cheap-inter-vlan-routing/ 
They cost in the same range as home wifi routers and I personally used them for a very similar thing as you are trying to achieve.
Access restrictions can be done via http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/Filter